# Passing an image from javascript to c# via blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

So I have this huge `Uint8ClampedArray` from `context2d.getImageData(....)`. The only way I managed to pass it to c# is using base64 encoding and decoding in c# but this is very slow (more than 5 seconds on my notebook).

Anyone found a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Blazor 0.5 there not more efficient ways to pass data.